# How can I get a list of the words that have six or more consonants in a row using the grep command?

Tags: regex, string, bash, grep, letter

I want to find a list of words that contain six or more consonants in a row from a number of text files.

I'm pretty new to the Unix terminal, but this is what I have tried:

```
cat *.txt | grep -Eo "\w+" | grep -i "[^AEOUIaeoui]{6}"
```

I use the cat command here because it will otherwise include the file names in the next pipe. I use the second pipe to get a list of all the words in the text files.

The problem is the last pipe, I want to somehow get it to grep 6 consonants in a row, it doesn't need to be the same one. I would know one way of solving the problem, but that would create a command longer that this entire post.

Comment: grep does not print the filename, if you use the `-h`  switch.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a sample input and output so we could better understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -hEio '[[:alpha:]]*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{6}[[:alpha:]]*' *.txt
```

**Regex details**

- `[[:alpha:]]*` - any zero or more letter
- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{6}` - six English consonant letters on end
- `[[:alpha:]]*` - any zero or more letter.

The `grep` options make the regex search case insensitive (`i`) and `grep` shows the matched texts only (with `o`) without displaying the filenames (`h`). The `-E` option allows the POSIX ERE syntax, else, if you do not specify it, you would need to escape `{6}` as `\{6\}`,

Comment: Why we need `[[:alpha:]]*` before and after ?

Comment: @Philippe To match any zero or more letters.

Comment: @Philippe See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/VYpdHg) to see why `[[:alpha:]]*` is important here.

Answer (score 3):

For the last `grep` you also need the `-E` switch - or you need to escape the curly braces:

```sh
cat *.txt | grep -Eo "\w+" | grep -Ei "[^AEOUIaeoui]{6}"
cat *.txt | grep -Eo "\w+" | grep -i "[^AEOUIaeoui]\{6\}"
```

> I use the cat command here because it will otherwise include the file names in the next pipe

You can disable this using the `-h` flag:

```sh
grep -hEo "\w+" *.txt | grep -Ei "[^AEOUIaeoui]{6}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'print for grep { /[^aeoui]{6}/i } /\b([a-z]+)\b/ig' in_file.txt
```

Example:

```
cat > in_file.txt <<EOF
the abcdfghi aBcdfghi.
ABCDFGHI234
abcdEfgh
EOF
```

```
perl -lne 'print for grep { /[^aeoui]{6}/i } /\b([a-z]+)\b/ig' in_file.txt
```

Output:

```
abcdfghi
aBcdfghi
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

The regex uses these modifiers:
`/g` : Multiple matches.
`/i` : Case-insensitive matches.

`/\b([a-z]+)\b/ig` : Match words that consist of 1 or more letters only (`[a-z]+`), **with words boundary `\b` on both sides**. This way, `ABCDFGHI234` does not match, but  all 3 words in line 1 (`the`, `abcdfghi`, `aBcdfghi`) match. This may be important for some applications. **Note that not all answers in this thread use the word boundary around letters, and thus do not make the distinction shown in this example.**

`/[^aeoui]{6}/i` : Match 6 or more consecutive non-vowels. Non-vowels here resolve exactly to consonants, because the previous regex selected for words made of *letters* only, that is, vowels and consonants.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

## Get all words containing 6 or more consonants in a row in a given directory

```sh
cat *.txt | grep -Eo "\w+" | grep -E "[^AEOUIaeoui]{6,}"
```

We can use `grep -Eo` (-E Extended regex, -o output ONLY matching)

`cat *.txt` will output all of the data from all txt files in the current directory
`grep -Eo "\w+"` will output all of the words from an input in the form of one word per line

We can use Regex to search for strings that contain a pattern:

1. `[^LISTOFCHARACTERS]` Any character but LISTOFCHARACTERS
2. `{6,}` 6 or more